# Unique column among 3 tables where one is optional

Tags: postgresql

```sql
CREATE TABLE a 
(
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b 
(
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE c 
(
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL,
    a_id INT REFERENCES a
    -- this doesn't have to belong to a
);
```

I am looking for a way to be able verify that all of these `slug` columns are unique.

The issue is that if `c` references `a`, then it shouldn't be unique among the `a` and `b` slugs, but rather unique among other `c` entries with the same `a_id`

I am aware it would be simple to create a new `slugs` table, however the requirement on the `c` table seems to make it not viable.

I do not want to split `c` into different tables just to manage this column.

*ver: PostgreSQL 11*

**Sample:**

```
a :
id| slug
--+-----
1 | wine
2 | beer

b :

id| slug
--+-----
1 | wine (this is not allowed because it conflicts with the a table)
2 | whiskey

c :

id| a_id | slug
--+------+-----
1 | null | wine (this is not allowed because it conflicts with the a table)
2 |   1  | wine (this is allowed because it references table a and should be treated differently)
3 |   1  | wine (this is not allowed because of the previous entry above)
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your requirements.. Can you add some sample data that would represent what you need ?

Comment: example data added

Comment: Your best approach is actually to do what you don't want to. Add a separate table for slug and associative table between the three table with a unique constraint on the the for relationship (a,b,c and slug). Though as mentioned in the answer below you could do this validation in a trigger. But I feel that you may not even need 4 tables. Explain what you are trying to achieve, we would be able to provide you with a better design all together. This one is not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

This really does sound like a poor design and your example data leaves raises as many questions as it answers/describes. For example:

- I cannot insert Wine into B, because it is already in A. But can I insert Whiskey (in B) into A, or are contents of A and mutually unique (that sounds strange).
- I cannot insert Wine into C without also a_id because Wine already exists in A. But can I insert Scotch into C, as it's not in A. If I can then what happens when I later insert Scotch into A, or is that not allowed.
- Can I insert Whiskey into C.

At a minimum you'll need a trigger function (perhaps more than 1) to validate your cross table checks "B vs A", "C vs A", perhaps more. You'll also need additional constraints on your tables. Is C.a_id defined as a FK to A or just a comment? Are there any unique constraints on any slug columns? etc.

You need to consider and post the combination of rules across all 3 tables.